# Showing wrong <X> to <Y> of <Z> entries in jquery-datables

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

I have problem with counting current showing rows in datatable.
1) first problem is [wrong number of current visible rows](http://prntscr.com/eruinx)
2) second is  [wrong start number of visible rows](http://prntscr.com/erujgn) . It seems like datatable count wrong heights of columns or something like this?

I am using dataTables.scroller.js 1.4.2 and jquery.dataTables.js 1.10.11

Settings for datatable:

```
function setupSearch() {
oJobAdSearchTable = $('#jobAdSearchTable').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    searching: false,
    "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
    },
    "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
    },
    fnDrawCallback: function () {
        var blabla = 0;
    },
    scrollInfinite: true,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: 550,
    scroller: {
        loadingIndicator: true
    },
    fnServerParams: function (aoData) {
        aoData["companyNameId"] = $("#inputCompanyNameId").val();
        aoData["jobAdHeadingId"] = $("#inputJobAdHeadingId").val();
        aoData["jobAdId"] = $("#inputJobAdId").val();
        aoData["fromDate"] = moment($("#datepickerSearchFromDate").datepicker("getDate")).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        aoData["toDate"] = moment($("#datepickerSearchToDate").datepicker("getDate")).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        aoData["partnerId"] = $("#valPartnerId").val();
        aoData["sessionId"] = $("#valSessionId").val();
        aoData["numJobAds"] = $("#valNumJobAds").val();
        aoData["lang"] = currentLanguage;
    },
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/searchjobadinfinite/get'
    }
});
};
```

This send request to C# method (sorry for big amount of code, i am not sure what can make influence to the issue):

```
public dynamic Get()
    {
        DataTablePager<JobTitleModel> res = new DataTablePager<JobTitleModel>();

        try
        {
            DateTime beginTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();

            NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);

            DOAReports.Args.SearchJobAdsArgs searchArgs = new DOAReports.Args.SearchJobAdsArgs(nvc);
            if (provider == null)
                provider = new ClickMapProvider();

            // Due to performance we use a low number
            searchArgs.TopNum = 250;

            DateTime beginSql = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            List<JobTitleModel> searchList;
            if (searchArgs.JobAdID != "")
                searchList = provider.SearchJobAdIdInfinite(searchArgs);
            else
                searchList = provider.SearchJobAdsInfinite(searchArgs);

            DateTime endSql = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();

            int totalNum = 0;
            if (CacheSessionProvider.Contains(KEY_SESSION_JOBAD_SEARH_NUM_TOTAL))
            {
                totalNum = Convert.ToInt32(CacheSessionProvider.Get(KEY_SESSION_JOBAD_SEARH_NUM_TOTAL));
            }
            else
            {
                totalNum = provider.NumJobAds(searchArgs);
                CacheSessionProvider.Add(KEY_SESSION_JOBAD_SEARH_NUM_TOTAL, totalNum);
            }

            int totalNumFiltered = totalNum;
            if (totalNumFiltered > searchArgs.TopNum)
                totalNumFiltered = searchArgs.TopNum;
            DateTime beginSerialize = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();

            var result = from sl in searchList
                         select new[] { sl.CompanyName, sl.Title, Convert.ToString(sl.JobAdId), sl.ProductPackage, sl.DateCreated.ToShortDateString(), sl.DateExpired.ToShortDateString(), Convert.ToString(sl.NumAppearances), Convert.ToString(sl.NumViews), Convert.ToString(sl.NumActions), Convert.ToString(sl.NumInterested) + " (" + Convert.ToString(sl.NumApplications) + ")", Convert.ToString(sl.JobAdId) + "," + Convert.ToString(sl.PrevJobAdId) + "," + Convert.ToString(sl.NextJobAdId) };

            DateTime endSerialize = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();

            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("From: " + searchArgs.FromRow + ", TO: " + searchArgs.ToRow + ", Elapsed: " + (endTime - beginTime).ToString() + ", Sql: " + (endSql - beginSql).ToString() + ", Serialize: " + (endSerialize - beginSerialize).ToString());

            DOAReports.Model.JobAdSearchTotal totals = provider.GetSearchJobAdInfiniteTotal(searchArgs);

            return new
            {
                draw = searchArgs.draw,
                recordsTotal = totalNum,
                recordsFiltered = totalNumFiltered,
                dataTotals = totals,
                data = result
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex);
        }

        return res;
    }
```

What can be the reason of this bug, can you help me please? I have already spend few days trying to find the cause. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your table initially hidden? If yes, you may need to call [`scroller.measure()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/scroller.measure()) to recalculate measurements Scroller uses.

Comment: It is not hidden. I tried $('#jobAdSearchTable').DataTable().scroller.measure() but id didn't help :(

Comment: Height of your rows is larger than the default DataTables style, and I think for some reason Scroller fails to calculate the correct row height and thinks that more rows are shown on the screen than there actually are. I would start by removing your custom style and see if that corrects the problem. Maybe you could replicate a problem on https://jsFiddle.net?

Comment: i will try to reproduce it on jsfiddle. Styles are not the problem, because i have already tried to remove all styles related to these rows and it didn't help

Comment: Finally, i found cause of the problem, as you said - that were styles. If i remove all styles - it will count correct.
So is it possible to make custom styles for datatables without this issue?